# ASP.Net - Link button not rendering proper html on Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have link button on my page which working fine on IE but is not working on Chrome and Mozilla. When I dig into , i found that its rendering html is this

```
<div >
  <a  id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Register" 
      href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions
      (&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Register&quot;, &quot; &quot;, true, 
      &quot;grpReg&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" >Register</a>
</div>
```

If we see we have `&quot;` inside our method, which is creating issue. So please help me in resolving this issue

TIA

Amit

Comment: show the actual asp linkbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks its solved. Actual by mistakes its viewstate was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in all browsers and works fine after I replace & nbsp ; with "

Perhaps it is an encoding issue?